# Event listeners fired multiple times from same directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ngroute, ng-view

In my app I am using a custom directive with a window resize event listener:

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
    angular.element($window).bind('resize', function() {
        // viewId is a unique reference to the view in which the directive lives
        console.log(scope.viewId);
    });
}
```

This directive is inserted 1 or multiple times in each of my views.

What puzzles me is why the function is executed not only for the active view, but also for inactive ones. This happens once I have accessed more than one view.

What puzzles me even more, is why the function is called multiple times from the same view, after I have visited the same view multiple times.

It seems to me that the old directive scope is not destroyed, but kept alive and a new scope is created on top of the old one.

Is there anything I can do to prevent this behavior?

---

Below a code snippet of the working solution based on the answer provided by Renan Lopes Ferreira (I am using LoDash _.debounce to prevent the function being called too often):

```
windowResize = _.debounce(function () {
    // My logic
    $scope.$apply();
}, 150);

// Attach debounced function to the window.resize event listener
angular.element($window).on('resize', windowResize);

// Remove the function when the directive is destroyed
$scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
    angular.element($window).off('resize', windowResize);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the listener when your directive is destroyed. Something like:

```
angular.element($window).on('resize', resize);

scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
  angular.element($window).off('resize', resize);
});

function resize(){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In directive link function is called one time for each directive with the same name angular found.

So if you have twice your directive in your view, it will execute the link function two times.

If you want to run your function only once, just do your stuff in the "compile" function.

Check this tutorial, he is great: http://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives/

Comment: Thanks for the useful input. In my use case it was OK for the function to be called multiple times for each directive in view, I just didn't want them to be called for destroyed directives.